# How to find the machine details, where virtual box is running

Tags: java, linux, virtualbox

i am using windows pc and running SUSE Linux on virtual box. i can get processor id and other hardware details of virtual machine (SUSE).

Is there any possibilities(commands or using languages like java) to get hardware details of the machine (Windows), using virtual box (SUSE)?

EDIT :

my requirement is to restrict virtual machine to run on a single machine. if user copy or clone the virtual machine to some other machine it should not work or i need to kill a process. is there any possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: Virtual box is emulating the hardware so you can't have these information inside your VM ... The VM is not aware about the virtualization process ...

Comment: i can get the mac address which is same on both. like that is there any other information we can get?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking for. Does the command `lshw` help?

Comment: lshw displays the virtual machine details not the hosted machine details

Comment: I have added your edit as a comment to my answer. However, in the future please open a new question instead of editing an old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

However, there is some info you can gather:

- The CPU information is usually passed into the guest 1:1, so a simple `cat /proc/cpuinfo` should show the actual CPU type most of the time. The number of cores may be wrong however.
- If you are behind a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and the host also has internet access, you can use something like `curl http://icanhazip.com/` to get the public IP address of your machine.
- The MAC address is not guaranteed to be the same, as you can set it to whatever you want in the VirtualBox settings.

Other than that, there is not much more information you can get from within a typical VirtualBox instance.

There is a [related question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/486696/what-information-about-a-vmware-host-is-available-to-the-guest) that describes the more general case and focuses on VMWare.

Comment: my requirement is to restrict virtual machine to run on a single machine. if user copy or clone the virtual machine to some other machine it should not work or i need to kill a process. is there any possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: The best way to do something like this would be to create a tamperproof/cryptographic hardware USB [Dongle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongle), and check if it is connected to the machine you are running on. VMWare and VirtualBox both support USB passthrough. Another way would be online product activation, but that only allows you to restrict the number of machines running your software, not the physical machine itself. Checking the physical machine without a hardware dongle is impossible, and even if you could do it, what would stop me from running two VMs? E.g. VM->VM->OS.